# Unable to upload app to iTunes Connect - iTunes Store operation failed. Authentication timeout

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload my app to iTunes Connect with Xcode. I chose product > archive, choose my account, it compiles and when I try to upload it hand for a long time on:

```
Uploading Archive
Sending API usage to iTunes Connect...
```

Then it shows an error message:

[image: Archive upload failed with errors: iTunes Store operation failed. Authentication timeout. Please restart Xcode]

I've restarted Xcode and the entire machine but still it keeps repeating itself.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried Application Loader? In case of an error it shows much more details.

Comment: Wow - having the same exact issue today trying to validate an archive. I just upgraded to El Captain and XCode 7.2.... what gives? Have been trying the past 3 hours same results... restarted XCode as instructed..did not help... what a piece of crappy software....I resisted upgrading for as long as I could anticipating these kinds of issues...

Comment: I added a possible answer..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My solution was to install Application Loader. At first it seemed like it's stuck as well, but after about 10 minutes it started uploading.

Answer (score 40):

This usually happens to me when the phone is connected while uploading the archive, and removing the phone so far has been solving the issue for me.

Comment: Strange but true. I had continual problems uploading with errors until I disconnected any iDevices. Then, like a hot knife through warm butter my app went on it's merry way to magic hq. This should be the accepted answer as it fixes the problem in Xcode without having to use an additional tool.

Comment: This worked for me as well. The main reason I think is that XCode still builds the app for the specific phone (not for the general selection) even though the phone is not selected. Or, XCode uses the Development signing identity to sign the ipa and thus it fails. Very weird thought

Comment: This solved the "rsync failed" error during the upload.

Answer (score 15):

I solved this issue.

There is a checkbox "include bitcode" at the bottom of the Summary screen (when you validate Archive) or Send XXX to Apple screen (when you upload to App Store) where the Organizer show the Binary and Entitlements together with Provisioning Profile. In XCode 7 it is checked by default. I unchecked it and re-run Validation - worked fine. As soon as checked the checkbox back on, it started failing with same error.

I have also unchecked the other checkbox on the same screen - symbolis upload.

Successfully uploaded the binary using the Organizr just now.

Comment: After about 10 failed upload attempts, I finally started Googlin' again and this worked first try. Too bad I don't know what "include bitcode" means haha

Comment: Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

Comment: Great answer! Saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Here the solution that helped in Xcode 8, summary screen:

[image: Summary screen xcode 8 fixing failed to upload]

Comment: Solved if you have error like archive upload error -23690, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Still getting the same error despite "unchecking" bitcode and also archiving with the bitcode under Basic Profile turned off in the info.plist.

It would only work if I used Application Loader, like this:

First, export the application Archive from Xcode's Organizer window (**it saves this into a directory on the Desktop**).

Then, from Xcode:

`Xcode` > `Open Developer Tool` > `Application Loader`

My guess is that there is a bug somewhere either with iTunes Connect back end or xCode itself.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of Xcode restart didn't resolve the issue but **Application Loader** solved it for the very first attempt. Also, Application Loader, is more descriptive for letting one know what's going on during the whole upload process. Plus simultaneous apps upload is possible via Application Loader.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when trying to upload an app to App Store Connect (01/20/2020). Restarting Xcode fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue.
Tried to upload the app with Transporter with no success.
Restarting of Mac and Xcode didn't help.

Solution was to logout from Xcode and log in back
Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Select your Apple ID and click on "-" below

Answer (score 1):

To submit to App Store use `Application Loader` but after creating the "App-Specific" password as the following:

1. Log in to https://appleid.apple.com and enter your 2FA (TWO-FACTOR AUTHENTICATION) code.
2. Then in the Security section on the bottom right area, you'll see: `APP-SPECIFIC PASSWORDS`.
3. `Generate Password...` Click the link to create an app-specific password, Enter your password.
4. Copy the app-specific password. Enter the password into the `Application Loader`.
5. Choose the exported `ipa` to submit it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For developers uploading apps with Xcode: simply change network **and** restart your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with Transporter, native Apple application. You can download it from AppStore.
https://apps.apple.com/ua/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

This application has a much more information about uploading process and possible errors.

1. Install the "Transporter" app from the MacOS app store.
2. From Xcode's organizer, select your archive and press "Distribute App"
3. Select "Export" and proceed as usual.
4. Choose the exported .ipa file into the transporter and press "Deliver".

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Application Loader didn't work.  I couldn't open any Apple Developer/Forum webpages either to find an answer there.  And iTunesConnect wouldn't let me log in.  I thought the site was down and I couldn't even access the Apple Status pages.

My VPN was connecting outside the US.  After turning off the VPN everything returned to normal.  I have been letting the VPN connect to random places around the globe, probably should keep it in my area.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, The build with the same number (e.g. **Version 1.0(1.6)**) was already been uploaded to AppStore. I found that after logging into itunes and checked the *TESTFLIGHT BUILDS -> iOS* and there I saw ***1.6 (Processing)***

Note: **1.0** is the version number and **1.6** is build number.