# App Store Connect Operation Error: Could not connect to Apple's web service

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have been trying to upload my app archive to App Store connect for the past 3 days. In the beginning, there was a problem with the iTMSTransporter and I had to manually install it from iTunes Connect. Now it fails when I try to upload it. This is the error that comes up.

[image]

I have tried googling about this problem and I couldn't find a solution that worked for me. I tried using application loader instead of organiser to upload and I still came across the same error. I also tried to not include bitcode when I uploaded the archive and it didn't work. When I use application loader, it seems that the error occurs when it is comparing metadata with the App Store. I am not really sure of what that means but maybe that may be the problem? It would be really helpful if I could get some help with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
I tried looking into the diagnostic report and this is what I got.

```
[2019-04-16 02:49:44 SGT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Version = 1.11.0
[2019-04-16 02:49:44 SGT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter iTMSTransporterMode = upload
[2019-04-16 02:49:44 SGT] <main>  INFO: id = 20190416024944-407
[2019-04-16 02:49:44 SGT] <main>  INFO: iTMSTransporter Correlation Key: 2a7ba74f-8686-4003-8d70-4793622d6094
[2019-04-16 02:49:44 SGT] <main>  WARN: Web service received a server status of: HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
[2019-04-16 02:49:44 SGT] <main>  WARN: Web service response received: <html>
            <head>
                <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
            <p>Socks5ProtocolException(&quot;SOCKS5 mode failure: SocksError(&#x27;Invalid SOCKS version. Expected 0x05, got 0x43&#x27;,)&quot;,)</p>
            </body>
        </html>
[2019-04-16 02:49:44 SGT] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation returned
[2019-04-16 02:49:44 SGT] <main> DBG-X: Sleeping for 4680 ms
[2019-04-16 02:49:49 SGT] <main> DBG-X: Done sleeping
[2019-04-16 02:49:49 SGT] <main> ERROR: Could not connect to Apple's web service.
[2019-04-16 02:49:49 SGT] <main> ERROR: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
[2019-04-16 02:49:49 SGT] <main>  INFO: JSON:{"msg":{"phase":"Upload","count":2,"description":"Operation failed","index":2},"messageType":"VerifyProgress"}
[2019-04-16 02:49:49 SGT] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1
```

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047557/unable-to-upload-app-to-itunes-connect-itunes-store-operation-failed-authenti

Comment: I have already tried the solutions that have been suggested in that question. None of them worked for me.

Comment: That doesn’t make your question a nonduplicate. The point is that this has been asked and answered before and your question adds nothing new to the mix, so repeating the question is pointless.

Comment: Restarting network connection **and** Mac made the job for me.

Answer (score 33):

I had the exact problem. It ended up a network configuration issue. Go to Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and make sure "Auto Proxy Discovery" and "Automatic Proxy Configuration" are checked but none of the other proxy options are checked. I had to uncheck "SOCKS Proxy" option to resolve the issue.

Comment: How did you figure out, thank you though!!

Comment: @Hooman Malek, SOCKS Proxy is unchecked in my case but I still have those errors. What should I do?

Comment: For me also not working

Comment: worked for me Xcode 13

Answer (score 6):

This helped me. I was trying for hours before I figured out that it was my network settings error. 
[image]

Comment: I was sceptical that this would help as it's never been necessary before but it seems to have resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I uploaded build at list 10 - 15 times but all time got this error - **"App Store Connect Operation Error"** because i upload build with slow internet speed. When i try with high internet speed, then build uploaded first time on app store.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you didn't increment your version and build number.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes experience it because I have more than one version of Xcode, and archives it in the beta version of Xcode.

> Make sure you do Archive only in the Xcode release version, not in
> Xcode beta or other versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was pushing all the iOS app builds via Xcode itself.
However, this kicked in one day and was searched on google. Saw this thread and also an Apple forum thread as well:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123649

Then I had to follow the solution of using Transporter which you can download from App Store app and sign in with the relevant Apple ID which you used to enrol for the developer license, and tried uploading, and it worked in one go.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Install the "Transporter" app from the MacOS app store.
2. From Xcode's organizer, select your archive and press "Distribute App"
3. Instead of "Upload", select "Export" and proceed as usual.
4. Drop the exported .ipa into the transporter and press "Deliver".

Worked great for both of my apps. Finally!

Answer (score -3):

Follow these steps:
- Go to Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and make sure "Auto Proxy Discovery" and "web proxy (HTTP)". 
- and try to Upload you app again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Afh.jpg)