# Unsupported Architectures, the executable for .app/Frameworks/...contains unsupported architectures [x86_64] on Flutter ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I got this error message when build an app to test flight. I used `Flutter` framework. `Generic IOS Device > Product > Archive`

[image: view full error message]

I tried to add this solution, but not working [I tried this solution from Daniel Kennett](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/)

my fully run script on ios.

```
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build

echo "Target architectures: $ARCHS"

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

echo "App Path: $APP_PATH"

find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
echo $(lipo -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH")

FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH="$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-tmp"

# remove simulator's archs if location is not simulator's directory
case "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}" in
*"iphonesimulator")
    echo "No need to remove archs"
    ;;
*)
    if $(lipo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -verify_arch "i386") ; then
    lipo -output "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" -remove "i386" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    echo "i386 architecture removed"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    fi
    if $(lipo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -verify_arch "x86_64") ; then
    lipo -output "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" -remove "x86_64" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    echo "x86_64 architecture removed"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    fi
    ;;
esac

echo "Completed for executable $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
echo $(lipo -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH")

done
```

Comment: It's not able to connect to app store, so it could be a network error. Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55756322.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Darshan network is not an issue. this question related to ios architectures

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue after I manually linked App.framework and Flutter.framework to the xcode project. In my case, it turned out that the order of build phases was wrong:

[image]

After moving the "Embed Frameworks" phase before "Thin Binary" phase, the errors disappeared.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me as well. I just need to put "Embed Frameworks" before "Run Script"

Comment: Lifesaver! Worked for me too