# Got Could not find latest iTMSTransport to download Bad Gateway when try to upload to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I tried to upload my latest build to iTunes Connect, but it shows the error below. This happened after I renewed my Developer account.

[image]

Here is the Application Loader Error Report

```
 INFO: Web service received a server status of: HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
[2019-06-13 17:11:57 IST] <main>  INFO: Web service response received: <html>
            <head>
                <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
            <p>Socks5ProtocolException(&quot;SOCKS5 mode failure: SocksError(&#x27;Invalid SOCKS version. Expected 0x05, got 0x43&#x27;,)&quot;,)</p>
            </body>
        </html>
[2019-06-13 17:11:57 IST] <main> ERROR: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
[2019-06-13 17:11:57 IST] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1
```

Comment: it looks like an issue with your network. did you check to see if you can access the Internet?

Comment: yeah, Connection is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find many problems like this and there can be any solution which might work for you.

To save time I would suggest you export the application Archive from Xcode's Organizer window (it saves this into a directory on the Desktop).

Then, from Xcode:

Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader

Also application loader is more descriptive for letting one know what's going on during the whole upload process.

Follow below reference which depicts same problem as yours :

[App Store Connect Operation Error: Could not connect to Apple's web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695236/app-store-connect-operation-error-could-not-connect-to-apples-web-service)

[Unable to upload app to iTunes Connect - iTunes Store operation failed. Authentication timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047557/unable-to-upload-app-to-itunes-connect-itunes-store-operation-failed-authenti)

Hope this helps.

Tip:- Problem was Proxy Settings

> It ended up a network configuration issue. Go to Preferences > Network
>
> > Advanced > Proxies and make sure "Auto Proxy Discovery" and "Automatic Proxy Configuration" are checked but none of the other
> >     proxy options are checked. I had to uncheck "SOCKS Proxy" option to
> >     resolve the issue.

Comment: If you are getting more descriptive error messages in the application loader please also add those to the question.

Comment: Updated Question

Comment: Are you able to open the itunesconnect in the Browser?

Comment: Yeah I can open

Comment: Added some reference links in the answer which can be useful to you.